# NGINX: Multiple locations with different SSLVerifyClient directives

Tags: nginx, location

I have several locations in my server description, for which different ssl_verify_client directives should apply (with values 'on' or 'optional_no_ca').
Basically I need something like this:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    
    location /pathA {
        ssl_verify_client on;
    }
    location /pathB {
        ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca;
    }
}
```

But ssl_verify_client only works on server level.
How can I still create such a case distinction?

I know the "trick" for the case where you have a location with 'ssl_verify_client optional;' (instead of 'ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca;).
Then you can simply set 'ssl_verify_client optional;' for all of them on the server level and add something like this to the locations that actually need 'ssl_verify_client on;':

```
if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
    return 403;
}
```

But with 'ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca;' this is not possible. Otherwise, in all cases client certificates that are not signed by a trusted CA certificate would be accepted.

Any ideas?
Many thanks in advance!